# merge multiple columns into rows based on different column values

Tags: linux, awk

I have an annotated dataset (tab-separated) and want to make a new file sorted by GeneName. Since the all the NoneGene has the same name in the file, I am having a hard time finding a way to sort them to get the desired output.

An example of my file:

```
GeneName    Pos SNP
NoneGene    1   22:1_A/T
NoneGene    2   22:2_A/G
NoneGene    3   22:3_A/C
Gene1       4   22:4_A/G
Gene1       5   22:5_G/T
NoneGene    6   22:6_T/C
NoneGene    7   22:7_A/G
NoneGene    8   22:8_T/G
Gene2       9   22:9_G/T
Gene2       10  22:10_C/T
NoneGene    11  22:11_T/G
Nonegene    12  22:12_A/C
```

Desired output:

```
NoneGene    22:1_A/T    22:2_A/G    22:3_A/C
Gene1       22:4_A/G    22:5_G/T    
NoneGene    22:6_T/C    22:7_A/G    22:8_T/G
Gene2       22:9_G/T    22:10_C/T
Nonegene    22:11_T/G   22:12_A/C
```

Each line in the desired output data is for one gene/set of SNP (for example 22:1_A/T), tab-separated. The first element in each line is the gene (for example NoneGene, gene1, NoneGene, gene2, etc), and the rest of the line is for variant ids written in form 22:1_A/T. How many SNP there are for each gene will vary. The SNP should be sorted from the lowest to the highest value (for example 22:1_A/T 22:2_A/G 22:3_A/C).

I would prefer an awk (or gawk) solution, but I am totally new to coding, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not awk, but the always handy [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) makes it easy:

```
$ tail -n +2 input.tsv | datamash -g 1 collapse 3  | tr ',' '\t'
NoneGene    22:1_A/T    22:2_A/G    22:3_A/C
Gene1   22:4_A/G    22:5_G/T
NoneGene    22:6_T/C    22:7_A/G    22:8_T/G
Gene2   22:9_G/T    22:10_C/T
NoneGene    22:11_T/G   22:12_A/C
```

This does assume that your input is already partitioned by gene and those further sorted by SNP value, as they are in your sample data.

- Strips the header line with `tail -n +2`
- Uses `datamash` to turn groups into lines that look like `NonGene 22:1_A/T,22:2_A/G,22:3_A/C`
- Uses `tr` to convert the commas into tabs for final output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in awk, try this, change delimiter to -F"\t"

combine all keys:

```
 awk -F" " '{  
  if(NR>1) {
   if ( length(a[$1]) == 0 ) {
      a[$1]=$3 
   }else { 
      a[$1] = a[$1]"\t"$3 
   }
  }
} END{ 
   for (e in a) { 
     print e,a[e]
   } 
} ' test.txt
```

If you want subsequent keys grouped, try this

```
 awk -F" " 'BEGIN{i=0; prev=""; }{ 
    if (NR>1) {
      if(prev==$1) { a[i]=a[i]"\t"$3; }
      else if(prev==$1 && length(a[i])>0) { a[i]=a[i]"\t"$3;   prev=$1;}
      else {i=i+1; a[i]=$1"\t"$3; prev=$1;}
    }
 }
END { for (e in a) print a[e]}
' test.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Another `awk`

```
awk '$1!=f {printf "\n%s %s ",$1,$3;f=$1;next} {printf "%s ",$3}' file

NoneGene 22:1_A/T 22:2_A/G 22:3_A/C
Gene1 22:4_A/G 22:5_G/T
NoneGene 22:6_T/C 22:7_A/G 22:8_T/G
Gene2 22:9_G/T 22:10_C/T
NoneGene 22:11_T/G
Nonegene 22:12_A/C
```

Without new line at front and add new line at end:

```
awk '$1!=f {printf (NR==1?"":"\n")"%s %s ",$1,$3;f=$1;next} {printf "%s ",$3} END {print ""}' file
NoneGene 22:1_A/T 22:2_A/G 22:3_A/C
Gene1 22:4_A/G 22:5_G/T
NoneGene 22:6_T/C 22:7_A/G 22:8_T/G
Gene2 22:9_G/T 22:10_C/T
NoneGene 22:11_T/G
Nonegene 22:12_A/C
```